# Magento Place order give undefined alert box

Tags: magento-1.8, javascript, onepage-checkout

Recently I have upgrade my Magento store from 1.3 to 1.8. I fixed almost errors. Now am facing a strange issue in the last step of the check out. When I click the place order button I get an undefined alert and nothing happens after that.

Somebody told me to alert transport.responseText on `skin/design/frontend/package/theme/js/opcheckout.js` to show the errors.

But I can't get any error in this alert. It just contains an html code of the check out page.

Anybody know what is the issue here.

Comment: I was having same issue and i fixed it by removing my checkout module .

Answer (score 3):

> app/design/frontend/default/YOUR_THEME/template/checkout/onepage/review/info.phtml

Find code

```
echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/saveOrder');
```

Replace it with:

```
echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/saveOrder', array('form_key' => Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey()));
```

Make sure to take file backup

Comment: i cant find $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/saveOrder'); on my info.phtml , my old magento version is 1.3 and upgraded to 1.8

Comment: Try disabling modules related to checkout

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        review = new Review('<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/saveOrder', array('form_key' => Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey())) ?>', '<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/success') ?>', $('checkout-agreements'));
    //]]>
    </script>
This code is in the end

Answer (score 3):

I had a same problem. Then i changed

```
echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/saveOrder');
```

to

```
echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/saveOrder', array('form_key' => Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey()));
```

But the template file's path is

```
app/design/frontend/default/YOUR_THEME/template/checkout/onepage/review.phtml
```

It worked for me.